# How to validate file path?

Tags: java, regex

Edit 1

I am stuck on a little problem and the guy who I normally turn to is, believe it or not, in Australia on his honeymoon, how inconsiderate is that.

The problem is that I have worked on trying to get a `boolean` which will either let me know if the file path is correct or not.

The problem is that it always returns false,

I have tried the following sample data

```
    c:\Lingerie\
    c:\\Lingerie\\
    c:\\
    c:\
```

**Edit**

This is the input screen that I have developed so far. I have already thought of having extra white spaces, so I already popped in the trim command.

[image]
They all have returned false.
Here is the method that I'm using and the code that calls it.

```
    dbFilePath = (text.getText()).trim();
    bool03 = busLog.isFilePath(dbFilePath);
    System.out.println("The result is " + bool03);
```

And the method is called is

```
public boolean isFilePath(String filePath) {

    return discreetLog.isFilePathMatched(filePath);
}
```

And which calls

```
public boolean isFilePathMatched(String myFilePath){

    String regularExpression = "([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+\\\\?";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);

    return Pattern.matches(regularExpression, myFilePath);
}
```

I don't know if it is my code or an input error.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?  What are you actually checking for?

Comment: *...the guy who I normally turn to is, believe it or not, in Australia on his honeymoon, how inconsiderate is that*. How inconsiderate from you for not letting him to rest few days! Back to your problem, should the path exists in the PC or is just a String validation?

Comment: If you do not take the compiled Pattern outside the method in a more global scope, `return myFilePath.matches(regularExpression);` suffices.

Comment: The first path of your sample matches the regex. See http://fiddle.re/e0h0r For the other paths, you need to change the regex though.

Comment: According to your pattern, the only _potentially_ matching entry is the second one (double-backslash required).  Since you don't show how the input values were provided we can't tell if there's extra whitespace at the end which would cause `matches` to fail since it wants to match the _entire_ input string.

Comment: @JimGarrison: according to his code, he is trimming his input at the beginning, so there should be no extra whitespace.

Comment: And since Java does not have raw strings, `\\\\\` just matches one slash, so it's the first path of the sample that potentially matches, not the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first path of your sample is actually matching the regex correctly.

To match the second and fourth, you have to allow double backslashes. Just add `\\\\?` on the right of the previous backslashes in your regex.

To match the third and fourth, you need to make the second group optional. Currently it is used with the operator `+`. Use `*` instead.

Therefore if you replace your regex with this one:

```
String regularExpression = "([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\\\\\?[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)*\\\\?\\\\?";
```

it will match all your paths, and nothing more.

If you still can not match your sample data, then there is a problem somewhere else in your code. You can try posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).